# Spring Data Neo4j find nodes by label

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I am currently using SDN 4 and trys to do the following query:

```
@Query("MATCH (n:TNode:{0}) RETURN n")
Collection<TNode> getNodes(String type);
```

where each node has a common label `"TNode"` and an individual label `type`. However, it always returns syntax error. I'm sure the query is correct because it returns nodes using Neo4j web client.

Does the error occurs because SDN can not find nodes by `label`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of Cypher, not SDN. Labels (or relationship types) as parameters are not supported. See [this and related feature requests](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4334).

You can work around this using where clause and labels(n) function:

```
MATCH (n:TNode) 
WHERE {0} in labels(n) 
RETURN n
```

This comes with a caveat - it will go through all nodes matched by the MATCH clause. In your situation having a :TNode label might solve the issue, but generally having simple MATCH (n) would go through all nodes in the database, which will be very slow.

Other option would be to build the query manually and use org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jOperations#queryForObjects to run the query:

```
String query = "MATCH (n:TNode:" + type + ") RETURN n"; // ugly, but works, beware of query injections etc..
Collection<TNode> nodes = neo4jOperations.queryForObjects(TNode.class, query, params);
```